# How to add multiple arrays in a single label text in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hi I'm using visual studio 2017 with vb.net as the language and connecting it to a database which is SQLEXPRESS 
This is my code and it keep on looping over and over without stop

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select MAX(VotePres) From PresidentTable", Conn)
    Conn.Open()
    TextBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
    Conn.Close()
    Dim max As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, max)
    Dim cma As New SqlCommand("Select Count('President') From PresidentTable Where VotePres ='" & max & "'", Conn)

    Conn.Open()
    TextBox1.Text = cma.ExecuteScalar().ToString
    Conn.Close()
 Dim cma As New SqlCommand("Select Count('President') From PresidentTable Where VotePres ='" & max & "'", Conn)

    Conn.Open()
    TextBox1.Text = cma.ExecuteScalar().ToString
    Conn.Close()
    Dim count As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, count)
    If count >= "2" Then
        Dim cmp As New SqlCommand("Select President From PresidentTable Where VotePres = '" & max & "'", Conn)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmp)
        Dim array(count - 1) As String
        adapter.Fill(table)

        For i = 0 To Array.Length - 1
            array(i) = table.Rows(i)(0).ToString
            Preslabel.Text = Preslabel.Text + "&" + array(i).ToString()
        Next


        Conn.Open()
        cmp.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Conn.Close()
Else
        Dim cmc As New SqlCommand("Select President From PresidentTable Where VotePres = '" & max & "'", Conn)
        Dim da As SqlDataReader
        Conn.Open()
        da = cmc.ExecuteReader()
        While da.Read()
            Preslabel.Text = da("President").ToString

        End While
        da.Close()
        cmc.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Conn.Close()
    End If
```

i wanted it to look like 
array(1) + array(2) and so on instead it keep on going forever until the program crash

Comment: `If count >= "2" Then` should really be `If count >= 2 Then` because count is an integer, not a string. Not the source of your problem, just a technical point.

Comment: @ADyson i tried it still gave me the same never ending loop

Comment: I did say "**Not the source of your problem**"...

Comment: Anyway, it's hard to see how this code could be producing an infinite loop. The only loop you've shown has got a definite ending. Here's a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iMsrpQ . Are you sure it's this section which produces the problem? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see what is really going on?

Comment: @Adyson ye sorry

Comment: @Adyson thats the only loop i made in that specific form so i keep on wondering what is happening

Comment: that's why you need to use the visual studio debugger to step through your code one line at a time and see what's _really_ happening. Then you can stop wondering :-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: @ADyson still doesnt point out any problem on the code

Comment: You claim it gets stuck forever...so presumably the debugger gets stuck too, and never goes to the next line, or just keeps going round and round the same lines of code? Where does it get stuck? What values are in the variables at that time? Does it throw any exceptions? Have you got any try/catch blocks which are covering up exceptions? I don't know, you'll have to investigate it more thoroughly. The only thing I can say with any certainty is that the loop in your code above is not the source of the problem.

Comment: change `Array.Length` in your for loop to `array.Length`

Comment: @preciousbetine VB.NET is not case-sensitive. See my dotnetfiddle link above for proof that it works despite the capital A.

Comment: My VS corrects the case of the A, a for me. It does not allow an uppercase A.

Comment: So, you only want to get the data if at least three records meet your criteria. Yes? What is `max` and where does it come from? Not entirely sure where the `End If` belongs. (It is missing)

Comment: @Mary the endif is on the end of all it since i got else after that

Comment: @Mary edited it shows the my whole form and its statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, max is an Integer. I am guessing this is referring to the President of a country, not the President of the Women's Club of Upper Montclair, NJ.

First command gets the maximum number of votes any President received.

Next, command gets the number of records where the number of votes matches the max. I can't imagine in any large election that this could be any more than one record. It has to be at least one record because you just did a search for max.

Now, you test this count to see if it is greater than 2.
Anyway, you retrieve the 3 of more records with votes equaling max and put that in a label.

If the count is 2 or 1 (it can't be zero because we returned max) then you put the data in a label and overwrite it with the data from the second record in the unlikely event that there is a second record.

So, I would forget the whole thing and just do

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
        Dim RetVal As String = ""
        Dim s = "Select Top 1 President From PresidentTable Order By VotePres DESC;"
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnectio)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(s, cn)
                cn.Open()
                RetVal = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
            End Using
        End Using
        Preslabel.Text = RetVal
End Sub
```

**EDIT** To allow for tie vote.
Okay, let's belt and suspenders this problem. We still don't need the count if we use a For Each loop. Although an aggregate function is not allowed in a Where clause it is allowed in a sub-query.

```
Private Sub OPCode2()
        Dim s = "Select President From PresidentTable Where VotePres = (Select MAX(VotePres) From PresidentTable);"
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnectio)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(s, cn)
                cn.Open()
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            PresLabel.Text &= row(0).ToString & vbCrLf
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: i dont understand how the code works i mean does Select Top 1 works as a querry in sql? i dont know that its possible plus why did you order it by desc and lastly what will happen if there are 2 or more records? im so curious about the code

Comment: retval = Cstr(cmd.ExcuteScalar) does this mean that if i get 2 equal VotePres it would add them in in retVal?

Comment: It is only going to return one record but if VotePres is the number of votes the President received, I doubt that there could be more than one record with the maximum number of votes. DESC stands for descending. And Top 1 returns the Top 1 record in the Order By. ExecuteScalar will return the first column of the first row of the data. Since we are only asking for one column and expect only one row, that should be it. Yes, the sql statement works for SQL Express. Did I answer everything?

Comment: Well in case there are two more record which i know is unlikely Im trying to be sure here so i need to at least try to get both in case that happens thats why im going to long way of taking everything into account since this is just a voting system for a university which could very likely be a tie so just incase better to be sure than to be sorry right?

Comment: OK, now I understand. I will edit my answer as soon as I get a minute. :-)